# Display the list of products in a tab

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.9

In my magento application i want to create a module which is for adding `FAQ` for a individual product. So while adding the `FAQ`, in the new tab i want to show the list of all products(like product listing) for which product we want to add `FAQ`.

So please help me how to customize for getting list of products and display in the new tab?

Comment: please eaborate your question. If you have more than 2000+ product, you need to show all of them in that tab ?

Comment: in which page you need to show this tab???

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is not proper and i'm new to magento.
Yes, i want to show all the records with pagination.In Faq page first tab will be the general information and the second tab will show list of products

And then click on save it will save Faq with selected product Id.

Comment: confusing. in which page you want to show your faq tabs. What you mean by tabs ? Means where do you want to appear your tabs in a particular page

Comment: Actually I have installed FAQ extension from here http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/faq-extension.html In this we can add question & answer in general information.

Comment: But now i want to relate this faq to individual product which we will select from list of products.

Comment: now question more is more clear. That means you need this faq appear in product view page (page that shows a product in detail) right ?

Comment: Exactly, For that i have searched the extensions but those are paid. So i wan to customize this extension like above.

Answer (score 1):

The question is too broad friend. So don't hope any full solution here. That is because, this question is related to an external extension. But you will get guidance here. Here you may need to do following things.

1. I think in admin, the  extension provides provision to manage each individual faque. What you need to do is, you need to create an extra field that will relate that faq with a product or multiple products.
2. If you set up this, you need to store this information in database. So for each faq, there may be a product id or multiple product ids related to it
3. Now you need to create a new block for your extension. This block will filter faqs that related to a particular product.
4. Next step is add above block in layout. Layout handle you need to use here is `catalog_product_view`.
5. Create a new template for your custom block and in that template file, you need to put design codes. You can create this template with the help of current template that this extension uses. That way, you can reduce a lot of time for creating the  design.

Hope that helps !

Comment: He need a fully coded solution not a structured solution.. But if he follows ur method, he will get the required output. +1 from me..

Comment: @PavanKumar : his question is too broad